# Book series where magic system involves building metal things (animals)-one of them can fly and drop orb like bombs

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I'm trying to remember a series I read and I can't for the life of me.

What I remember the most is the magic system, it's about a young man and he builds metal animals with lots of glyphs and stuff he has to write on them and some precious stones for eyes and other parts.
He gives them certain senses like sight, hearing and he can see through them and control them.

I distinctly remember a battle where the guy is running to safety behind a town wall and he has 2 dogs and 1 flying thing. The flying thing can drop orbs that explode. He's trying to make sure all the towns folk make it to safety and has to make a big show of it.

Also remember he wrote on paper as well to create small spies.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know when you read the series?

Answer (score 6):

**A Crucible of Souls (Sorcery Ascendant Sequence #1)**

> What I remember the most is the magic system, it's about a young man and he builds metal animals with lots of glyphs and stuff he has to write on them and some precious stones for eyes and other parts.

The protagonist is a young man. He was orphaned and raised by monks. He travels to the city to become a sorcerer. Sorcery in this world can involve bringing inanimate constructs to life by inscribing them with glyphs.

> Also remember he wrote on paper as well to create small spies.

Paper is one of the easiest materials to work with, and it's what the protagonist starts with. He makes what are essentially origami animals that are animated by his glyphs.

I didn't finish the book so I can't comment on other aspects.

> If it Helps I remeber the series wasn't finished being written, That's actually why I'm looking for it. I was hoping to see if the next book was released.

The series is fairly recent. The first book was released in 2013

Comment: @DidrikEtholm If this is indeed the one you can mark it as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the side of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds kinda like [*The Unwanteds*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9917879-the-unwanteds) by Lisa McMann. (It's a [YA series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/67764-unwanteds).)

> What I remember the most is the magic system, it's about a young man and he builds metal animals with lots of glyphs and stuff he has to write on them and some precious stones for eyes and other parts.

The whole premise of the book is that kids who have "imagination" are deemed unwanted. They would be thrown into a pit of boiling something-or-other except there's a mage who (secretly) saves them and brings them into a magical world that he created, and everything in that world is created by arts and imagination. For example, one of the main non-human characters is Simber, a giant winged cheetah.

The cheetah was crafted out of sand with preserve spells and things, but the main character also builds creatures later in the series, like a whale which he makes with seaweed, a whale skeleton, and a diamond encrusted horn.

> He gives them certain senses like sight, hearing and he can see through them and control them.

The animals created by magic have life unless the head mage of Artime dies

> which actually happens in the second book, so the main character must take over as head mage.

So they can certainly see and hear. I couldn't find a reference for the "seeing through their eyes" bit.

> I distinctly remember a battle where the guy is running to safety behind a town wall and he has 2 dogs and 1 flying thing. The flying thing can drop orbs that explode. He's trying to make sure all the towns folk make it to safety and has to make a big show of it.

The main character had two cats, one in Quill (the non-mage world) as a spy and one in Artime for the Quill-cat to communicate with. The flying thing is probably Simber.

> Also remember he wrote on paper as well to create small spies.

I read the books a while ago and remember something similar to this, but I can't actually find a source for this and I don't remember the specific circumstances.

See the front covers of the books below (Simber is the giant winged creature on the cover of the first book):

[image: The Unwanteds front cover] [image: Island of Silence front cover] [image: Island of Fire front cover] [image: Island of Legends front cover] [image: Island of Shipwrecks front cover] [image: Island of Graves front cover] [image: Island of Dragons front cover]

Comment: I've edited in the front covers for all the books in the series because they seem like they would be very memorable.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. However, this isn't the series I'm searching for. The hunt continues!

Comment: @DidrikEtholm *::dramatic theme music plays::* okay, I'll keep looking =)

Comment: If it Helps I remeber the series wasn't finished being written, That's actually why I'm looking for it. I was hoping to see if the next book was released.